# Where are the installed libs/apps/programs in Mac?

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, macports

There seems to be several different locations where a installed lib/app can go, depending on how it's installed. I am not sure where to look for a particular one. As far as I understand:

1. Preinstalled apps are in /Applications, /usr/bin, /usr/lib
2. Macports install things under /opt/local/bin, /usr/local/lib
3. Homebrew put files in /usr/local/cellar and symlink to
   /usr/local/...
4. Compilation with a Makefile can go anywhere, usually in
   /usr/local/...

What about /Library/Frameworks/ ? How is something installed there? Can I delete it just by removing the folder? Can things installed in different ways have dependencies in between? How does it work??

Answer (score 0):

OS X installs system components into /System and /usr.

Some 3rd Party bits (and Apple products other than the OS) are install to /Library

Some 3rd Parties (like Homebrew) install to /usr/local

MacPorts by default installs to /opt/local and /Applications/MacPorts

Fink by default installs to /sw